# how to restrict one user account to only certain applications on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, account

I created one account for my son on my ubuntu PC. I just want him to use learning software, not to open a browser or other software that has nothing to do with learning.

How to do this on ubuntu 22.04?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I never did it myself, but seems `Ubuntu Parental Controls` does the same thing.

Main Page saying

```
Parents can use the Parental Controls application to prevent children from accessing harmful content.

An administrator can use this application to:

Restrict a user's access to web browsers and applications.

Prevent a user from installing applications.

Allow a user to only access age-appropriate applications.
```

See the page [Ubuntu Parental Controls](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/parental-controls.html.en)